# My bootstrap collapse menu not working on Google Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu

My bootstrap collapse menu not working on Google Chrome !!!
its always be visible by default , and  i cant collapse it

my navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href=http://198.23.80.242/><img src="img/Go-ejaza-logo.png" width="85" height="28"></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse" style="height:auto !important; ">                       
                <ul class="nav nav-link">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >الوجهات</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-menu" >
                            <div class="span6">
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span4">
                                        <li class="nav-header">آسيا</li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/my" >ماليزيا</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/id" >اندونيسيا</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/ph" >الفلبين</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/th" >تايلاند</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/mv" >المالديف</a></li>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span4">
                                        <li class="nav-header">أوروبا</li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/at" >النمسا</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/tr" >تركيا</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/it" >أيطاليا</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/gb" >المملكة المتحدة</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/ch" >سويسرا</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/es" >أسبانيا</a></li>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span4">
                                        <li class="nav-header">الشرق الأوسط</li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/eg" >مصر</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/ae" >الإمارات</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/lb" >لبنان</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/ma" >المغرب</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://198.23.80.242/country/bh" >البحرين</a></li>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    <div class="nav pull-right visible-desktop ">
                    <ul class="unstyled login-div nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://198.23.80.242/hauth/login/Facebook"><span class="facebook"></span>دخول ب facebook</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://198.23.80.242/member/register">
                            <span class="join"></span>اشترك
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="login"></span> دخول
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu span3">
                                <form action="http://198.23.80.242/member/login" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                                <fieldset class="row-fluid">
                                <input type="text"  id="user_email" name="identity" class="span12" placeholder="البريد الالكتروني">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset class="row-fluid"> 
                                <input type="password" id="user_password" name="password" class="span7" placeholder="كلمة المرور">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-info pull-left">تسجيل الدخول</button>
                                </fieldset>
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox">تذكر كلمة المرور
                                </label>
                                <a href="http://198.23.80.242/member/forgot_password" style="color: red;">نسيت كلمة المرور</a>                                    </form>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="nav pull-left hidden-desktop ">
                    <ul class="unstyled login-div nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://198.23.80.242/hauth/login/Facebook"><span class="facebook"></span>دخول ب facebook</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://198.23.80.242/member/register">
                            <span class="join"></span>اشترك
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="login"></span> دخول
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu span3">
                                <form action="http://198.23.80.242/member/login" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                                <fieldset class="row-fluid">
                                <input type="text"  id="user_email" style="width:80%"  name="identity" class="span12" placeholder="البريد الالكتروني">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset class="row-fluid"> 
                                <input type="password"  style="width:80%" id="user_password" name="password" class="span7" placeholder="كلمة المرور">

                                </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset class="row-fluid" >
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-info pull-center">تسجيل الدخول</button>
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" style="margin-top:5px;">تذكر كلمة المرور </label>
                                   <a href="http://198.23.80.242/member/forgot_password" style="color: red;">نسيت كلمة المرور</a>                                       </fieldset>

                                </form>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

its not working on chrome only :( the firefox  is a great ... any help guys

Comment: I don't see any issue on Chrome 31. Where precisely should we look ?

Comment: @zessx , the nav bar by default open in small screens  , im all the browsers now :(

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<div class="nav-collapse" style="height:auto !important; ">`

Where `!important;` will cause your problem. Also read: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

If your intention is to have the menu opened on first load (or resize) use in your html:

`<div class="nav-collapse collapse in" style="height:auto;">`